# Returning response from an asynchoronous call not working in Emberjs Helper

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, ember.js, rsvp-promise

I'm trying to return a response from an ajax call to the Ember js helper. An `Asynchoronous` call using **Promise** in Helper is returning `[object Object]`.

`console.log(data.thumbnail_url);` is working but the **callback** is not returning the (`<img...>`)response. Here is [JsFiddle](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gupequleqo/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
   // for simply showing the problem, I've put the instagram id
   // Actually I will parse the id from the post body
   return ['fA9uwTtkSN'];
  }
});

Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper("format-inst", function(input){
 // Add this part
 if (typeof input == 'undefined'){return;}

 function foo (URL) {
   return $.ajax({
       url: URL,
       dataType: "jsonp"
  });
 }
     var URL = 'http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/'+input;
     var r = foo(URL).done(function (data){
                console.log(data.thumbnail_url);
                return '<img src="'+data.thumbnail_url+'">';                        
     });
     return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(r);
 });
```

Here is the HandleBars Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

 {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
 <ul>
 {{#each post in model}}
  <li>{{format-inst post}}</li>
 {{/each}}
 </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: https://github.com/instructure/ic-ajax Use this for ajax calls . and get the call back in .then(cb, failure);

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can return a promise from a helper.  I think you could put all the ajax in the route, for example after the model function:

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
var imgs = Ember.A([]);
controller.set('imgs', imgs );

model.forEach( function(imgId){
  var url = 'http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/'+imgId;
  $.ajax({url: URL, dataType: "jsonp"}).done(function(data){
    imgs.pushObject(Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('<img src="'+data.thumbnail_url+'">') );
  });
});
```

}

Then in the template just bind on imgs:

```
{{#each image in imgs}}
  <li>{{image}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

As the ajax calls complete, the Ember Array will get updated, and automatically update the template.

Comment: Thanks, But I guess you didn't notice the comment in the code. That is, these are not separate images. There're inside the post body and I want to show them like that not as separated.